# chrome extension injext code can't edit XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

while I develop chrome extensions, I find that inject code can edit other properties such as `window.name` but can't edit `XMLHttpRequest`. the main code such as these:

```
// manifest.json

"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs"
],
"content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : ["http://*/*"],
    "js" : ["inject.js"],
    "all_frames" : true ,
    "run_at" : "document_start"
}]

// inject.js

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
  console.log(1)
}
```

and finally I try to send a get request but the request is also `[native code]`

Comment: Are you sure? I try to rewrite XHR in `inject.js` but it seems inoperative, and I try to use other way such as write script tag in `inject.js` but the execution sequence I can't control. If you can do this, can you push some code here, Thank you

Comment: Ah, the file name has confused me, usually this name is used for scripts injected into the page DOM, but this one is a content script so it runs in an *isolated world*. See [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)